# What does KafkaConsumer.commitSync() actually commit?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does [KafkaConsumer.commitSync](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync--) just commit "offsets returned on the last poll()" as JavaDoc claims, (which may miss some partitions not included in the last `poll` result), or it is actually committing the latest positions for *all* subscribed partitions? Asking because the code suggests the latter, considering `allConsumed`:
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L1387

```
@Override
public void commitSync(Duration timeout) {
    acquireAndEnsureOpen();
    try {
        maybeThrowInvalidGroupIdException();
        if (!coordinator.commitOffsetsSync(subscriptions.allConsumed(), time.timer(timeout))) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout of " + timeout.toMillis() + "ms expired before successfully " +
                    "committing the current consumed offsets");
        }
    } finally {
        release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only commits the offsets that were actually polled and processed. If some offsets were not included in the last poll, then those offsets will not be committed.

It will **not** commit the *latest* positions for all subscribed partitions. This would interfere with the Consumer Offset management concept of Kafka to be able to re-start an application where it left off.

From my understanding, the `allConsumed` is equivalent to `all offsets included in the last poll` which the comment of the `commitSync` also documents

> Commit offsets returned on the last poll() for all the subscribed list of topics and partitions.